# Can I "LOCK IN SHARE MODE" without a transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, database-locking

Do I need to start a transaction in order to create a lock in share mode lock?

Ie, either,

```
$dbc -> query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE");
```

Or,

```
$dbc -> beginTransaction();
$dbc -> query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE");
$dbc -> commit();
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to take a lock if your transaction consists of a single query?

Comment: Because I need to make sure the information that is gathered from the query is the latest available.

Comment: @newtover is right - a single select is perfectly atomic, and in this case does not need the transaction nor the lock. You would only need a lock if you were going to use the result in another db operation within the transaction, such as an insert/update.

Comment: @halfer, this query can actually read modified rows from not commited transactions, but will wait until they are commited.

Comment: @newtover - do you mean the full query containing the `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, or just the `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1`? My understanding is that a simple select (on its own or inside its own transaction) will be unaffected by another pending transaction.

Comment: @halfer, the query with the modifer can read uncommited data, the query without the modifier can not (assuming the default isolation level is `repeatable read`) (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you start a session with autocommit enabled (which is usually default in PHP) the transaction is started and commited for you. If you call `beginTransaction`, it is actually should be translated into:

```
SET autocommit=0;
START TRANSACTION;
```

and commit should return autocommit back.

That is you do not need to explicitly start a transation  and commit it if you run in autocommit mode.

P.S.: You actually do not need to start a transaction even when you run in `autocommit=0`, because no changes will be commited until you execute `commit;`